# meteorjs keyup event for template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am following a [Meteor.js tutorial](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/managing-todos/), but I am stuck at this one point.

```
'keyup [name=todoItem]': function(event){
  console.log("You just tapped a key on your keyboard.");
}
```

is not working

Here is my code:

```
Template.todoItem.events({
  'click .delete-todo': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var documentId = this._id;
    Todos.remove({_id: documentId});
  },
  'keyup [name=todoItem]': function(event) {
    console.log("just tapped key on keyboard");
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the HTML for your `todoItem` template?

Answer (score 0):

The above code seems correct and I'm not sure what the real problem is.
Try the following:

1. Give an id=todoItem to the element, and use #todoItem instead of [name=todoItem] to see if that works.
2. Check if you have rightly named the template to "todoItem"
3. Try on another browser.

If none of the above works, the problem is probably in some other part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the above code is correct. Please read carefully:

All of these event types react to **when keys are pressed on a keyboard**..

You can try by press any keyboard and see console log; you aren't seeing anything currently because you are not pressing on the keyboard.